# How do i level up archery fast in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I already readed lots of guides about how to level archery fast but after my level is hight enough i needs hours to level please help me my archery skill is 51

Comment: Use the strongest bow you can find and use it on your own horse. You might have to use heal spells that are on target which also increases Restoration too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing skyrim on PC, their are mods which allows to train yourself (archery, etc...) on training dummnies

http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/23698/?